# Codeigniter, Displaying results from database

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI, I've been working on this for hours with no success, please help! I am trying to generate user profiles by retrieving information from a database and displaying it in the view (using the USERID). I am getting both an Undefined Variable Error and Trying to Get Property Out of Non-Object error. Here is my code:

Model:

```
 public function my_data()
{
  $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');

  $data = array();
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('user_profile');
  $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result();
  }
```

Controller:

```
    public function profile()
{

         $data['query'] = $this->user_model->my_data();



         $this->load->view('header_loggedin');
        $this->load->view('sidebar_left');
        $this->load->view('user/user_profile', $user);
        $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

View:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-user"></i>
            Name: <?php echo $row->name; ?>     
</div>
    <div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-home"></i>
            Location: <?php echo $data->location;?> 
</div>
        <div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-briefcase"></i>
            Occupation: <?php echo $data->occupation;?> 
</div>
```

Thanks so much in advance, I feel like I have tried everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as new to CI you will face some problems but later you will enjoy it here are some simple stuff you are doing wrong

Model

```
public function my_data()
{
  $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');

  $data = array();
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('user_profile');
  $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  //this will return multiple rows or object of arrays
  //return $query->result();
  // you need to send only single row
    return $query->row();
  }
```

Controller

```
public function profile()
{
         // in data array key name should be same which you will pass to view    
         $data['row'] = $this->user_model->my_data();



         $this->load->view('header_loggedin');
        $this->load->view('sidebar_left');
        $this->load->view('user/user_profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

View

```
<div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-user"></i>
            Name: <?php echo $row->name; ?>     
</div>
    <div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-home"></i>
            Location: <?php echo $row->location;?> 
</div>
        <div class="control-group">
 <i class="icon-briefcase"></i>
            Occupation: <?php echo $row->occupation;?> 
</div>
```

for more information please read CI user guide you will understand so many stuff from there [CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

Comment: hi i think he shoul pass $data to the view , not $user :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I am still getting the same two errors. Any idea what could be going wrong? I am still getting the undefined variable and 'trying to get property of non-object' errors.

Answer (score 0):

here change **$user to $data**

```
public function profile()
{

         $data['result'] = $this->user_model->my_data();



         $this->load->view('header_loggedin');
        $this->load->view('sidebar_left');
        $this->load->view('user/user_profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

then if your query returns only one row , you can use

```
return $query->row_array();
```

instead of

```
return $query->result();
```

in view you can now use

```
Name: <?php echo $result['name']; ?>
Location: <?php echo $result['location'];?> 
Occupation: <?php echo $result['occupation'];?>
```

Comment: I tried it this way and it says the variable Result is undefined.

Comment: really sorry , try my update now . i changed $daqueryta['result'] to $data['result']